# Regex for preg_match of a basic sentence

Tags: php, preg-match

I am new to regex.  I have a comment input section on a php form that will actually be email body text, to be sent using mail function. I want to use preg_match() to do a basic check to make sure it only has sentences (numbers, letters, standard punctuation) and not malicious code etc.

I found this as a suggestion but it doesn't seem to work.

```
([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?]\s)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This pattern will do what you want:

```
[^\d\s\w\.\?\,]
```

When used with preg_match() it will return an array with the first match. preg_match_all() will return an array with all matches. Matches in this case are disallowed characters.

I suggest you play with this pattern in the RegExp Tester I recommended below:

If you are new to RegExp I recommend to use a RegExp online tester. There are many of them. This is just an example: http://www.phpliveregex.com/.

This will help to understand how to deal with RegExp.

Comment: Since it is more an advice than an answer, you should post this as a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately you can only answer questions. In this case there is no question. So I can only give advices. But at least you are right :)

Comment: The question is, what is a good regex that will allow letter(upper and lower), numbers, puncuation (. , ! ?) ?  Generally check for valid sentence structure.  Since there are many experts in the forum, I thought it would be an easy question...tnx

Comment: The problem is, that you ask for something, that is not working like you think it works. preg_match() is searching for one or more matching patterns and returns an array with the matching groups. If you had used my advise, you may have found out this by your own...instead of down voting.


This pattern will do want you want: `[^\d\s\w\.\?\,]` When used with preg_match() will return an array with the first match. preg_match_all() will return an array with all matches. Matches in this case are not allowed files.


I suggest you play with this pattern in the RegExp Tester I recommended.

Comment: @Mister Dood: It is very nice, that you delete my answer with my clearification in the comments, so that the one I wrote this answer for, cannot see it. Good job, buddy. And you are right, I answered this way, because I wasn't able to comment on the original post. Again...good job.

Answer (score -1):

The adage goes "Once upon a time, a programmer had a problem. He thought he would use RegEx to solve the problem. Now, he has two problems."

There are actually plenty of other functions that do exactly what you want, without the hell of Regex.

Try any of these:

```
if(ctype_alnum($yourSentenceString)){ //proceed, string is safe. } 

$filteredString = filter_var($yourSentenceString, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
// ^There are lots of flags, besides FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING that will suit other needs.
// FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is a good one, for example...
```